# WPF Application Relative path to a mp3 sound file

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, mp3, relative-path

I'm building a WPF project with Visual Studio 2012 and I'm finding a problem with relative paths.

In the specific, I want a sound to be played when a ToggleButton is checked.

This is the code for my button:

```
<ToggleButton Name="Circles" Margin="88,104,86,172" Background="#FFFFD0CD" Foreground="Black" Checked="Circles_Checked">Circles</ToggleButton>
```

and if I write like this:

```
    private void Circles_Checked(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    MediaPlayer mplayer = new MediaPlayer();

    mplayer.Open(new Uri("C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\RehabilitationGUIProject\\RehabilitationGUIProject\\circles.mp3", UriKind.Relative));

    mplayer.Play();
    }
```

everything works as espected. But I want this code to work also onto other machines, not only mine. And what If I have to move the sounds to another location? I would like to use relative paths and move every sound inside my project folder.

So I created a new folder named Sound inside my root project, the structure is like this:

RehabilitationGuiProject
\Properties
\References
\Bin
\Object
\Sounds
 \circles.mp3

... other files .xaml

So I wrote the same lines of code above, changing this one:

```
mplayer.Open(new Uri(@"/Sounds/circles.mp3", UriKind.Relative));
```

But no sound is played. Which is the correct relative path for playing sounds from a project folder?

Comment: You can only play files directly from the file system, not those embedded as a "Resource" in your assembly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path must be relative to the folder where your application is executed.

```
mplayer.Open(new Uri(@"../../Sounds/circles.mp3", UriKind.Relative));
```

(Assuming your exe is run from the Bin/Debug folder)

Comment: Instead of jumping out of the Debug folder (by prepending ../../) you can mark the mp3 file as "Content" and "Copy if newer" in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer. Visual Studio will then copy the mp3 file to the correct location.